# Wordpress REMOVE VIEW CART link from the product page after adding item to the cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to remove View Cart link on the product page of Woocommerce which appears after you have added item to the cart?
I did try all the solutions offered by google but they didnt work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You said you tried *all* solutions, but they didn't work. What ones did you try? Please post some of the code you tried or at least the methods you tried as well. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `.woocommerce-message { display:none; }`